# Why appears "there is no package called [packagename]" to publish a shiny app?

Tags: shiny

I can't publish my shiny app on the server, it always gives the error "there is no package called [packagename]". I already changed the library directory to public with `.libPaths()` but it still gives the same error. My operating system is Windows. Would anyone have a tip?

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execução interrompida
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by server? Have you checked that on the server you want to publish your app, the package `tidyverse` is installed?

Comment: As the error says, you're missing a library